# Try to play a .mov file in Vue, unable to complie

Tags: vue.js

A .mov file is necessary to cater Safari users.
However in vue:

```
<video
       id="myvideo"
       autoplay
       muted
       loop
       playsinline
     >
       <source src="@/assets/01/output2.mov" type="video/quicktime" />
     </video>
```

When I trying to compile, "npm run serve" to start the local host:

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                    5:40:14 pm

error  in ./src/assets/01/output2.mov

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Not sure what to do, i try to instaill a package: File Loader, setup some config in vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.mov$/, use: 'file-loader' }
    ],
  },
}
```

However, after i try to run it again, it saids: "Module is not allowed"

My package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "gsap": "^3.8.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-cool-lightbox": "^2.7.4",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.26.3",
    "vue-meta": "^2.4.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-slick-carousel": "^1.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@intlify/vue-i18n-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "~2.3.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
```

Thank you all kindly~!

Comment: Did you manage to solve that issue?

Comment: file-loader should be a dev-dependency

Answer (score 0):

For me it went through like this

```
module.exports = {
  productionSourceMap: false,
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('mov')
      .test(/\.mov$/)
      .use('file-loader')
        .loader('file-loader')
        .end()
  }
}
```

My package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@lottiefiles/lottie-interactivity": "^1.2.0",
    "@lottiefiles/lottie-player": "^1.4.5",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-axios": "^3.4.0",
    "vue-meta": "^2.4.0",
    "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.4.0",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass": "~1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "stylus": "^0.55.0",
    "stylus-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-axios": "~0.0.4",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  },
```